# What are the specifics of the fake Yerushalmi story?

Tags: history, talmud-gemara, tannaim, talmud-yerushalmi, amoroim

I heard, long ago, about a mesechta (or entire seder, I can't recall which) of Yerushalmi that was fabricated. It was finally proven to be a fake when a rabbi realized that every mesechta (or seder) in shas has its own unique figure, whether that's a tanna or amora or what-have-you, and this mesechta (or seder) did not.

Is anyone familiar with the specifics of this story, and where can I find more about it?

Comment: https://blogs.yu.edu/news/the-forged-yerushalmi-a-20th-century-controversy/ http://www.zomet.org.il/eng/?CategoryID=160&ArticleID=7233

Comment: The mentioned R' Oberlander wrote his PhD dissertation about this topic. You may try your luck with Google Translate to read it: https://dea.lib.unideb.hu/dea/bitstream/handle/2437/92880/ertekezes.pdf

Comment: It might be more accessible for you, so here are a few articles by R' Oberlander in Hebrew: https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=13591&st=&pgnum=147 https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=13592&st=&pgnum=157
https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=13593&st=&pgnum=143
https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=13594&st=&pgnum=62
https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=13595&st=&pgnum=170
https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=13625&st=&pgnum=149

Answer (score 10, accepted):

https://www.yerushalmionline.org/articles/yerushalmi_on_kodshim.pdf Rabbi Yosef Gavriel Bechhofer's terrific article about it.

It was the Yerushalmi on all of Seder Kodshim.

Rabbi Yosef Rosen of Rogachov is the one to whom the one-new-rabbi-per-mesechta story is attributed:

> [image: It is worthwhile to note that according to an unverified legend related in the Yeshiva world, Friedlander's creativity was flawed. The legend maintains that Rabbi Yosef Rosen (the Rogatchover), one of the greatest masters of Talmudic knowledge of all time, realized that the work was a forgery because he had noticed that each tractate in the Talmud contains the name of at least one Amora who is never mentioned anywhere else. In his care not to raise doubts as to the work's legitimacy, it seems that Friedlander only used the names of known Amoraim!]

If I'm not mistaken, someone actually did find the Rogachover's note about this in one of his written works, somewhere in Tzofnas Paneach if I recall?

Comment: I didn't reread the article but I think he disproves the legend. Or at the very least it's disproven.

Comment: @robev I just read the article. He doesn't disprove the legend, but he does imply that it's untrue: "The Rogatchover's actual objections to the Yerushalmi on Kodashim are detailed in his responsa, _Tzafnas Paneach_ (Jerusalem, 1979), chaps. 113–115." (Sounds like the legendary one is _not_ "actual".)

Comment: Link is broken, can you update?